# parse.com query, key issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform

I am querying a List of ParseObjects, the issue is that if the object has an empty/null value for a key, the key is not returned in the query object. So my question, how can i see if the key is returned? When i try to access the key, i get an error stating that the key does not exist.  I am using c# and an MVC web application.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

```
    var query = from usrFull in ParseObject.GetQuery("UserFull")
    orderby usrFull.CreatedAt descending
    select usrFull;
```

simple query, but some results that come in have null values for some keys in the parse object, these keys are not reurned at all.

```
    ParseFile pf1 = record.Get<ParseFile>("profilePicture");
```

for the first row returned this key is empty, and the error gets displayed at this line. When i do a breakpoint at that line i see that the reurned keys are only the ones that have values.

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: What does the mapping look like and how is it possible to have more than one null key? I mean if it is a key at most one can be null.

Comment: the object has 10 fileds, if one or more of those fields are null (dont have a value for) the above query returs the objects but ommits the pair key-value for witch the value is null or empty.

Comment: OK can you show the actual query probably in the GetQuery method. I do not see any key/value pairs in the code posted here.